# Python - Execute sql statements from list of files in a folder and create output files for each of them

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following script to read the sql queries from each file in the folder and then write the output data to a different folder for each file. I am using pandas here. Do I really need to use pandas here as I am not doing any data manipulation. If so, how can execute the scripts and save the output?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB['servername'] + ';DATABASE=' + DB['database'] + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')

os.chdir(input_path) 

for filename in glob.glob('*.sql'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: # open in readonly mode
    
        query = open(filename, 'r')

        df = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(),conn)
        output_file_name = filename.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ] + '.txt'
        output_file = os.path.join(output_path, output_file_name)
        df.to_csv(output_file, sep='\t', index=False)
        query.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: you're opening the file twice.

Comment: searching for "pyodbc execute query" got me here in two clicks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#run-query

Comment: this is rather a rather convoluted process

Comment: basically, no, you don't need pandas. but if it's already installed, why reinvent the wheel?